# ERROR: could not load library plpython3u postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpython, postgresql-15, postgres-plpython

I'm trying to install the plpython3u extension in my postgresql with this command: `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;`

mas eu recebo este erro:

```
ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/15/lib/plpython3.dll": unknown error 126
```

My postgresql is in version 15 and was installed from the EDB website. Reading the postgres documentation (found at: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\doc\installation-notes)
I saw that version 15 of postgresql requires python 3.9

```
NOTE: On Windows we are keeping older Perl version

Perl 5.26
Python 3.9
Tcl 8.6
```

So I did that, I installed version 3.9 of Python, set the environment variables (both user and system) but the same error persisted

So I tried to install plpython through the Stack Builder language pack, and there I saw that it installed Python 3.10, and also set an environment variable called `PYTHONHOME%` with this path: `C:\edb\languagepack\v3\ Python-3.10`
In other words, something is probably wrong in the PostgreSQL documentation.
When I saw this I uninstalled python 3.9 (and all environment variables) and installed python 3.10 and added environment variables for both user and system, but the same error persisted

so I went to: `"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/15/lib/plpython3.dll" to see if my plpython3.dll` was present, AND IT IS PRESENT

Any idea what I can do? I really don't know what else to do to solve the problem

to summarize what I tried to do:
read the version requested in installation-notes (I tried but it didn't work)
install the version that appears in Stack Builder (but it didn't work)
I also tried

copy the dll C:\Python\Python310\python310.dll to C:\Windows\System32\python33.dll (name changed from python310 to python33, I saw a guy on a forum who did this and it worked)
and in my system32 python3 is also present

Comment: 1) Did you follow all the steps here [Language Install](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/language_pack/latest/installing/windows/)?  In particular a) *Using the graphical installer* and b)  *Configuring Language Pack with PostgreSQL on Windows*  2) Don't know if this is a copy/paste error but this `C:\edb\languagepack\v3\ Python-3.10` should be `C:\edb\languagepack\v3\Python-3.10`.  Also per 1) b) the Windows PATH needs to have settings added.

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver. Yes, I was able to follow this tutorial, and an environment variable called: PYTHONHOME% was automatically set to the path: C:\edb\languagepack\v3\Python-3.10
but that didn't solve the problem yet

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here *Go to This PC > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables.* and add the appropriate paths to the system PATH?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I was actually forgetting an environment variable
I added the missing variable, I managed to create the extension, but now the error I receive is: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend. x.x

Comment: I/O error occurred when you where doing what?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver When I tried to run a test function in plpython3u, creating the extension worked, but when I ran a test function, it gave me this error that I mentioned above

Comment: That is a separate issue. Create a new question with the function code and the complete error message.